# My regex format not working properly

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to write a regex to select `<del></del>` tag along with the text preceding it, but with no spaces beside `start <del>` tag or `end </del>` tag.

Either there is no space before start tag or no space after end tag it must select. No need to check both the conditions that there must be no space between any of the start or end tags. Any one tag also it must select.

For that I have written the below regex

```
 ([^\s]+)(\<del)(.*?)(\<\/del\>)([^\s]+)|([^\s]+)(\<del)(.*?)(\<\/del\>)|(\<del)(.*?)(\<\/del\>)([^\s]+)
```

It's working fine for the text in following link https://regex101.com/r/mD8zF7/2

But when I cross checked by changing the text as the following. It's giving some wrong output https://regex101.com/r/mD8zF7/4

What is the modification that I should make in my regex? or what is the correct regex format for my requirement.

please help me out. Thank you !!

Comment: I'd recommend using [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/), it's my favourite tool for debugging regex.

Comment: It is because of `.*?` and `(\w+)`. The match is attempted and found. This is why regular expressions are not safe with XML/HTML.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331703/duplicate-question-by-same-user-same-answerer-a-year-later), because a duplicate of it was asked again a year later, by the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\w+)?<del(.*?)<\/del>\s*(\w+)|(\w+)<del(.*?)<\/del>\s*(\w+)?

                      ^^                             ^^
```

The `space` was causing the problems because `.*?` was being expanded until non space words were being found. See this demo:

https://regex101.com/r/mD8zF7/8

After `.*?`  your regex was looking for `\w+` but in your new example there was a `space` before `\w+`.So it was matching until it would `\w+` without space.

Comment: In your case it's working perfectly fine. But when one more <del> tag is added beside a matched text. it's not grouping the <del> tag along with it. You can see here https://regex101.com/r/mD8zF7/9

Comment: In the third line you can see there is a <del> tag after welcome. Actually it must group the <del> tag preceding welcome along with that match. But it's not grouping

Comment: can you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834868/regex-timeout-error-jquery-javascript

Comment: Thanks!! it really helped

Comment: one last help. I am trying to identify tags inside tags like "word<del class="del"><del class="del">word with or without space</del></del>word" and "<del class="del"><del class="del">word with or without space</del></del>word" and "word<del class="del"><del class="del">word with or without space</del></del>" and "<del class="del"><del class="del">word with or without space</del></del>" and "word<del class="del">word<del class="del">word with or without space</del></del>word" and "word<del class="del"><del class="del">word</del>word</del>word" and

Comment: "word<del class="del">word word<del class="del">word</del>word</del>word"etc, all such cases in which only the <del></del> tags which are nested inside the <del></del> are to be identified

Comment: I have reached question limit. I can't post a question

Comment: @rjirji post a regex101 link with question and expected answer

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/28 this is the sample text with regex. Notice that there is <ins></ins> tag inside of another <ins></ins> i.e, a nested tag. such tags are not identified in the regex. The identification is getting breaked before the nested tag starts. I am trying to solve that issue

Comment: Hi.. Please modify the regex https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/28 such the regex identification must stop only when a space and special characters is identified in between <ins></ins> and it must must in all these cases. There can be html tags in between <ins></ins> or there can be another set of <ins></ins> inside <ins></ins>. If there is a space inside nested tags like "can-be-anything-before-or-not<ins><ins>wo rd</ins></ins>can-be-anything-before-or-not" it must stop at "can-be-anything-before-or-not<ins><ins>wo" as there is a space after this

Comment: here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869675/correction-in-regex