# Timeout errors with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a content with `<del></del>` and `<ins></ins>` tags. I have a regex which satisfies the conditions which are clearly explained in the image

[image]

The regex which satisfies the conditions is:

- https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/19

This regex is working perfectly fine. But, when the content is more or When the matching content is long the execution time is increasing and hence throwing a timeout error which can be seen in

- https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/20

How to simplify the regex

```
(\w*(?:(?:(?:<del\b[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/del>).)*<\/del>)|(?:<ins\b[^>]*>\w+<\/ins>)|(?:\w+<\/ins>)|(?:<ins\b[^>]*>\w+))(?:\w+|))+)
```

to avoid it from throwing timeout error?

Comment: The comments in the linked (deleted) question explain that a DOM Parser should be used, this still appears to be the case.  You should edit and add example input and expected output.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8iNWl.png this is the explanation required. Here you can see the example which already satisfies the conditions in the image. But in the following regex https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/20 you can find the text is lengthy and so it is giving timeout error. I just want to simplify my regex such that it gives a fast response however long the content may be

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/21 the content in this link is same as that of https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/20. I have removed few lines of content in the beginning to show what is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not correct way to do this.You yourself have discovered a pitfall.
There will be more.So switch to DOM parser .As for removing the timeout issue , you can try

```
((?=(\w*))\2(?:(?:(?:<del\b[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/del>).)*<\/del>)|(?:<ins\b[^>]*>\w+<\/ins>)|(?:\w+<\/ins>)|(?:<ins\b[^>]*>\w+))(?:\w+|))+)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/24

Comment: I will try the DOM parser once. But in the new regex which you have posted the word before the opening tags is not getting selected in the regex. Example "the<del class="del"> </del>andrelated" must be selected instead of "<del class="del"> </del>andrelated" and

Comment: "s<del class="del">t</del>at<del class="del">e</del>m<del class="del">e</del>n<del class="del">t</del>s<ins class="ins>d</ins>" must be selected instead of "<del class="del">t</del>at<del class="del">e</del>m<del class="del">e</del>n<del class="del">t</del>s<ins class="ins>d</ins>"   and   "error<del class="del">.</del>" instead of "<del class="del">.</del>"